# Luminance 'y' value of surface texture

Tags: textures, opengl-es, fragment-shader

For my opengl video player app, I am using surface texture bound to GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES

source : https://github.com/crossle/MediaPlayerSurface/blob/master/src/me/crossle/demo/surfacetexture/VideoSurfaceView.java

In my fragment shader, I want luminance value to be taken for 3x3 block.

```
vec2 tex00 = vec2(vTextureCoord.x-xmargin, vTextureCoord.y-ymargin)
vec4 p00 = texture2D(sTexture, tex00)

... etc for 3x3
```

and then calculate luminance of each texel : ie: p00 by doing dot of p00.rgb with vec3 of (0.3,0.59,0.11).

Instead is it possible to directly use p00.y ? Will it give luminance value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not. In GLSL vectors have three sets of swizzle masks: `xyzw`, `rgba` and `stpq`. The implied semantics (coordinates, color and texture coordinates) are there to help the developer only. They all access the same set of data.

`p00.y`, `p00.g` and `p00.t` will all return the same value, in this case the green component of the texel.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Is there any way to get texture in yuv format directly so that I dont have to do this conversion.? I am trying to optimize the app and this RGB-YUV conversion is creating a performance drop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MediaPlayer component you are using, but maybe you could tell it somehow to output YUV instead of RGB? How significant is this performance drop anyway? Dot products should be cheap.

Comment: I have added a question for that : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119052/create-yuv-texture-for-gl-texture-external-oes-format                                                                                                  FPS drops from 60 to almost 30 on doing this conversion.

Comment: If there's no change in semantics, shouldn't that be `p00.t`?

Comment: You are absolutely right! :)