# Create YUV texture for GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES format

Tags: opengl, shaders, textures

0
down vote
favorite

I need to create a yuv texture for GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES format.

source : https://github.com/crossle/MediaPlayerSurface/blob/master/src/me/crossle/demo/surfacetexture/VideoSurfaceView.java

I am doing all processing on YUV, so it would save clock cycles, if I can generate a yuv texture as output of texture2D.

To get 'y' value, I need to take dotproduct of each texel with vec3 of (0.3,0.59,0.11) Since, for my purpose I need to take 3x3 pixel block's 'y' value and take a convolution of them, this results in performance impact. So it would save clock cycles, if I can generate a yuv texture as output of texture2D.

Comment: what is the convolution you are doing? why do you think a YUV texture would help you when the actual slow operation is the convolution? also, please show your entire shader code.

Comment: I am doing all the processing on YUV values, so ends up converting all texel RGB values to YUV. Thought it would save cycles if I can directly use YUV.   I am using Gaussian blur convolution.

Comment: I doubt the dot product is the limiting factor here. That's the kind of no-sweat work the GPU can burn through easily while it's waiting for samples to arrive from the texture unit. I'd recommend doing a two-pass blur. The first pass samples 3 pixels in a row and outputs a greyscale luminance blurred horizontally. The second pass samples 3 pixels of this texture in a column (no conversion needed since it's already luminance-only) and outputs the final 3x3 blurred luminance texture. If that's an acceptable solution I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: Yes, please. I would really like to try it out. If possible can you give a sample of how to do the 2 pass.

Comment: I don’t recommend doing a 2-pass blur for a 3×3 kernel, as I believe it will be slower. There are more efficient methods such as taking advantage of linear sampling. Again, *please show your shader code* or there is no way we can help you properly (you won’t get an upvote from me until the question is complete; the code you’re linking to isn’t the code you’re asking about).

Comment: I’m voting to close this. “cant paste shader code because of confidentiality issues” makes the question too vague and unhelpful for anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sam hocevar](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/5864/sam-hocevar), in a comment above, recommends making use of hardware blinear filtering like this pseudocode:

```
sample = (vec4)0;

sample += tex2D(sourceTexture, sourceTexelUV + (1/2 texel stride) * (-1, -1));
sample += tex2D(sourceTexture, sourceTexelUV + (1/2 texel stride) * ( 1, -1));
sample += tex2D(sourceTexture, sourceTexelUV + (1/2 texel stride) * (-1,  1));
sample += tex2D(sourceTexture, sourceTexelUV + (1/2 texel stride) * ( 1,  1));

float blurredLuminance = dot(sample, luminanceCoefficients/4f);
```

(I've also seen this implemented where we compute U and V ± 1/2 texel stride in the vertex shader, and pass those four values to the fragment shader rather than computing this constant offset per-fragment)

How are we getting a 3x3 kernel with only 4 samples? Each sample is exactly at the corner between 4 texels, so with the texture filtering mode set to bilinear we'll get an average of all 4 texels returned to us very efficiently, since sampling & blending of each texel is implemented in the hardware.

Summing all these pre-blended samples, the math works out that we get a final blend that's 1 part from each corner, 2 parts from each cardinal neighbour, and 4 parts from the center texel - exactly the relative weights we want from a 3x3 Gaussian blur.

Since the dot product is linear, we can do it once on the accumulated result, dividing by the number of samples at the same time (this can be combined into one constant).

I agree with sam that this is probably faster than my 2-pass suggestion. I'd forgotten that separating Gaussians into 2 passes is mainly an efficiency for larger filter kernels, and for a 3x3 kernel it would actually result in more texture sampling workload than the single-pass version outlined here.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want to try.
I am still learning shader basics so have some more questions on this solution.
When you say texture stride, what is it actually,.? In my vertexData, I have X,Y,Z,U,V. (3 position and 2 UV texture cordinates).
So is stride 5 * sizeof float ? or 2 * size of float? or is it actually distance between 2 texels? ie: 1/width and 1/height and then taking half of that to get corner?

Also, you have done lumcoefficients dividing by 4.
Lumco-efficients are vec3 (0.3, 0.5, 0.2)
So can I assume it is dot of (sample.rgb /4) and lumCoeff

Comment: Texel Stride is the UV distance between two texels, so 1/(texture width, texture height) as you describe. Keeping the division by 4 on the luminance coefficients allows that to be combined into a single constant, but that's not a big deal. You can do the dot product between two vec3s or vec4s, whatever you find neatest.

Comment: Didnt get the correct yconvolve after implementing. Can you please check.  "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
" vec2 scale = vec2(1,1)/vec2(offsetx,offsety);\n" +
" vec4 p00 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord + 0.5*scale*vec2(-1,-1));\n" +
" vec4 p02 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord + 0.5*scale*vec2(1,-1));\n" +
" vec4 p20 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord + 0.5*scale*vec2(-1,1));\n" +
" vec4 p22 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord + 0.5*scale*vec2(1,1));\n" +
" vec4 pconvolve = 0.25*(p00 + p02 + p20 + p22);\n" +
" float yconvolve = dot (pconvolve.rgb,lumcoeff);\n" +

Comment: Sorry for indentation issues. There is character number limitation for comments.

Comment: @user81246 it sounds like you should post a new question. That will give you lots of room to format your code correctly, show how you're calculating offsetx & offsety, how you've configured your texture filtering, and how your rendered results compare with what you expect. We won't be able to troubleshoot all of that in the comments. ;)